# I am looking for some help in using sql db sequence in EF6 - DB First

Tags: entity-framework

Here is the Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace myAPI.Models
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            [Key]

            public int employeeId { get; set; }

            [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
            public string employeeName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The employeeId in the table is not using Identity instead using ***(NEXT VALUE FOR [seqEmployeeId])***. DatabaseGeneratedOption Enum supports only three values as `{0-None; 1-Identity; 2-Compute}` and Enum Value 2 is for both update and insert.

Issue is when I try to do a REST POST get this exception.

```
"exceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the Column is changed to Identity then it works fine with the data annotation but I can't leave the column as identity since the Id sequence has some intelligence built in.

Comment: Just don't ever expect a primary key (a *surrogate key*) to have a specific value (which you apparently do when it is generated with *some intelligence*). Use an identity field as PK and besides that, your generated key as a computed column.